# Can a graph have 7 vertices and 4 edges?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I need to prove whether a circuit-free graph with 7 vertices and four edges can exist. I've been trying to draw various different types, and I have not been able to find one that works because I believe that the amount of edges is too few for it to work. But I also don't really know how to prove that, instead of just saying that I can't find one that works. Any help or direction would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Such a graph exists but cannot possibly be connected.

Comment: Oh right, not all of the vertices have to be connected for it to be considered a graph, correct?

Comment: That is correct.